# Failed to load application context due to NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am new to DI using spring boot and running into this issue while trying to use a bean from an external library. My application is failing to start complaining that the bean defined in the external library is failing to instantiate complaining of `Factory method 'xyz' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/UnifiedJedis`. The pom.xml file for the external library has the dependency added as

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
 <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
 <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I can get this to work if I add the same dependency in my `pom.xml` file, but it fails if I remove the dependency from my project's `pom.xml` file. Why do I need to explicitly add this again when it is already defined in the external library's pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can be loaded in multiple different ways. For one of its dependencies, a library can load either only the API, or both the API and implementation. Some libraries will load only the API so that the host application can choose the implementation, allowing you to use any version of the library that supports the given API, and prevents a situation where another library requires a different but compatible version of the same API. I can't say for sure what is happening here, but it sounds to me like Jedis is loading only the API and relying on the host application to import the implementation. Therefore unless you provide an implementation of `UnifiedJedis` in your application, then the class won't be found.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can check if the library is loading only the API and expecting a implementation to be provided? I want to understand how this is being done under the hood so that debugging in the future becomes easier.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure with maven because I don't really use it. With Gradle you can tell based on the function used, i.e. `api` vs `implementation`. Maven most likely has something similar to this.